# How to view a regression tree?

Tags: machine-learning, plot, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am wanting to visualize my decision tree applied to regression (only this plot for classification worked) what is going wrong that only the values appear but not the tree built itself?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For a simpler approach, try:

```
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
.
.
.
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(X,y)

clf.plot_tree()
```

The`plot_tree()` method uses matplotlib tools to make a tree visualizer.
For a fancier approach, you can plot the tree using graphviz. Check out this article about this topic:

https://towardsdatascience.com/visualizing-decision-trees-with-python-scikit-learn-graphviz-matplotlib-1c50b4aa68dc